# get only website name

Tags: c#, wpf

I have, for example, the following URL:

http://www.beta.microsoft.com/path/page.htm

and I need to retrieve the name from it, which in this case is:

microsoft

I need to get the name of the website - without the sub-domain, www, .com extension and other stuff - only the name.

How do I get it in the fastest and most convenient way?

Din.

Comment: do you mean the 2nd part of the domain or a page title?

Comment: dinbrca you are after the company name not the website name

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you mean the *domain name*:

```
new Uri(string).Host
```

Comment: @dinbrca: That's actually rather hard to define.  What about `test.whatever.co.uk`?

Comment: If you can get me the function that gets whatever from test.whatever.co.uk or from whatever.co.uk or whatever.com it will be good :) thx btw

Comment: Then you need a list of public suffixes (`.co.uk` vs `.us`)

Answer (score 1):

You could make a Array with all the domain extensions, replace that with String.Empty to remove it and then pick the last item from Split('.'). This will give you what you want most of the times. Otherwise it is not possible to know which part is the right one.

UPDATE:
This code does what wanted, but i'm guessing there is a better way for this, maybe regex or something in that direction.

http://pastebin.com/SVkiJ1Vq

Comment: I guess it's really hard to extract what I want :( thx anyway guys